# Parameter mismatch exception even the parameter count is correct

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, moq

Please refer the below code.

Method signature in the Interface

```
OrganizationVM GetParty(int param1, int param2, int param3);
```

Test method

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetOrganizationByPartyRoleId()
    {
        int param1 = 1;int param2 = 1;int param3 = 1;
        OrganizationVM org = this.MockManager.GetParty(param1, param2, param3);
        Assert.IsNotNull(org);
    }
```

Test project's constructor

```
int partyId = 2;
mockPartyManager.Setup(mr => mr.GetParty(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>())).Returns((int i) => organizationList.Where(x => x.partyID == i).Single());
```

This throws

> Parameter count mismatch.
>   exception. How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `GetParty(int param1, int param2, int param3)` with 3 parameters, but in `Returns` call you are using only one. Change it to something like this

```
.Returns((int i, int j, int k) => organizationList.Where(x => x.partyID == i).Single());
```